# I am new to PL/SQL.Can some one help me in this PL/SQL procedure?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Write a PL/SQL procedure which takes employee number and salary as input parameters and delete from employees table whose manager is 'BLAKE' and salary between 1000 and 2000.

I have written below code :-

```
create  or replace procedure processing(v_emp_no in emp1.empno%type,v_salary in emp1.sal%type)
is 
begin

select empno,sal into v_emp_no,v_salary
from emp where ename = 'BLAKE' and sal between 1000 and 2000;
delete from emp1
where empno  = v_emp_no
and sal = v_salary; 
end;
```

Getting below error :-

> Error at line 5: PLS-00403: expression 'V_EMP_NO' cannot be used as an INTO-target of a SELECT/FETCH statement

Comment: That is exactly what you have done; why then are you ignoring the input parameters? What are you actually trying to do here?

Comment: Yes, I know what error you'd be getting (though it's always better if you put this in your question, which you can [edit]). However, that's not what I asked. Your code makes no sense. If you're inputting those parameters why are you trying to overwrite them? Why not just use them to perform the delete? If you're not wanting to delete the values which you input I see no particular need to have them as parameters. So, what are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: I don't want to overwrite parameters using fetch ...I want to pass thru procedure call ...But not sure how to do...So want help as I am in learning phase.Please write ur code snippet if u understand problem statement.

Comment: Do you want to pass the parameters for deletion? if so why are you using select in the SP? and what exactly are your input parameters? do you want to input the employee number and existing salary as input and check if the employee's salary is within 1000 and 2000 range and then delete?

Comment: yes i want to pass parameters for deletion.Select statements ..yeah i shouldn't use then....input parameters are employee number and salary and yes two conditions i have to check 1. if  manager is 'BLAKE' and 2. salary between 1000 and 2000

Comment: Prefixing the variable names is clumsy and unnecessary, even if it is a widely used technique. Name them the same as they are in the table, and when you use them in a SQL statement qualify them with a block name: "... where empno  = processing.empno and sal = processing.sal".

Answer (score 5):

The input parameters cannot be assigned value in function or procedure and also your input parameters are not used as input hence declare them as local variables and use them.

```
 create  or replace procedure processing
 is 
  l_emp_no emp1.empno%type;
  l_salary  emp1.sal%type;
 begin
  select empno,sal into l_emp_no,l_salary
  from emp where ename = 'BLAKE' and sal between 1000 and 2000;
  delete from emp1
  where empno  = l_emp_no
  and sal = l_salary; 
 end;
```

call the procedure as

```
begin
 processing;
end;
```

**Edit1**:- if you need to get output of emp_no and salary deleted 
in emp1 use the out parameter.

```
 create  or replace procedure processing
 (v_emp_no OUT emp1.empno%type,v_salary OUT emp1.sal%type)
 is 
  l_emp_no emp1.empno%type;
  l_salary  emp1.sal%type;
 begin
  select empno,sal into l_emp_no,l_salary
  from emp where ename = 'BLAKE' and sal between 1000 and 2000;
  delete from emp1
  where empno  = l_emp_no
  and sal = l_salary; 

  v_emp_no:=l_emp_no;
  v_salary:=l_salary;
 end;
```

Call them as

```
declare
p_emp_no emp1.empno%type;
p_salary emp1.sal%type;
begin
 processing(p_emp_no,p_salary);
 dbms_output.put_line('the employee deleted in emp1 is '||p_emp_no);
 dbms_output.put_line('the employee salary is '||p_salary);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that "v_emp_no" and "v_salary" is an input to your procedure (IN).

If you want your procedure to be able to modify it (being able to put a value into it) then you need to tell the procedure that by declaring it IN OUT in your procedure.

For example, you have:

```
v_emp_no in emp1.empno%type
```

You need:

```
v_emp_no in out emp1.empno%type
```

Edit 
What you maybe better can do is make a cursor for the "select null from emp where ename = 'BLAKE' and sal between 1000 and 2000". And then look if that one return you any values. If that is the case you can hava a boolean be put on TRUE.

And later have IF fBoolean THEN delete ..... 
That way you don't have to overwrite "v_emp_no" and "v_salary".

Comment: Yes, but there's absolutely no point doing this; 'cause you're going to always overwrite what you input, so there's no point inputting any data, which is exactly what the OP wants to do.